# How to sum metrics in Prometheus across jobs

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have two jobs configured in promethus.yml

```
- job_name: serviceA
  scrape_interval: 60s
  metrics_path: /
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - serviceA:8080
- job_name: serviceB
  scrape_interval: 60s
  metrics_path: /
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - serviceB:8080
```

Both services have a counter metric named in each **metric1** in serviceA; and **metric2** in serviceB.

In Grafana and the Prometheus site the expression metric1 + metric2 does not return anything. I tried multiplication, division, etc but no results either. And same result with gauge metric as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metrics must have the same labels and values.

If "metric1" has labels "labelA" and "labelB", and "metric2" has labels "labelA" and "labelC", "metric1 + metric2" will return nothing.

If "metric1" has label "labelA" with "A" and "B" values, and "metric2" also has label "labelA" but with "C" and "D" values, "metric1 + metric2" will return nothing.

You can try to use functions to aggregate common labels and values, for example:

```
sum by (label1) (metric1) + sum by (label1) (metric1)
```

Comment: Hi,
My metrics are like this if I one by one "print" them in Prometheus:

metric1{instance="serviceA:8080", job="serviceA"} 3

metric2{instance="serviceB:8080", job="serviceB"} 4
So since I do not have the same label values is that an issue?

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer to add more info.

Comment: I have tried sum by (job)(mertic1) + sum by (job)(metric2) that did not work, however, sum by ()(mertic1) + sum by ()(metric2) worked and even works with *, /, etc

Comment: It didn't work because you have different values for job ("serviceA" and "serviceB"). You could just use "sum(metric1) + sum(metric2)" instead of "sum by () (mertic1) + sum by () (metric2)".